# Meteor Form Submission

Tags: javascript, form, meteor

I am hoping a Meteor guru can please review my code below and verify if I am properly using `return false` and `event.preventDefault()`, especially in the context of form submission.

The reason being, [the Meteor docs](https://www.meteor.com/try/4) use this approach:

```
// Prevent default form submit
return false;
```

while other tutorials use this approach:

```
event.preventDefault(); //prevent page reload
```

So I want to be sure that I am on the correct path before I proceed with the rest of my code.

Basically, my code gets the value of the `username` input and checks if the value exists in the database:

**HTML**

```
<template name="registration">
    <p class="message {{#if message_defined}}display_element{{/if}}">{{message}}</p>
    <form id="register_form">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
    </form>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // This code only runs on the client

    Meteor.subscribe("users");

    Template.registration.helpers({
        message: function () {
            return Session.get("message");
        },
        message_defined: function () {
            return Session.equals("message", undefined) ? false : true;
        }
    });

    Template.registration.events({
        "submit #register_form": function (event) {
            // This function is called when the registration form is submitted.

            event.preventDefault(); // Correct usage?

            var form_data = {
                username: event.target.username.value,
            };

            if (!Match.test(form_data.username, String)) {
                Session.set("message", "username must be a string");
                return false;  // Correct usage?
            } 

            if (form_data.username.length < 6) {
                Session.set("message", "username must be at least 6 characters");
                return false;  // Correct usage?
            }

            Meteor.call("check_username",form_data.username,function(error, result){
                if (error) {
                    Session.set("message", error);
                    return false;  // Correct usage?
                }
                if (result) {
                    Session.set("message", result);
                    return false;  // Correct usage?
                }
            });
        }
    });
}


Meteor.methods({
    check_username: function (username) {
        // If user exists, return error.

        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username:username});
        if (user) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("username exists", "That username is already in use.");
        }

        return "username not found";
    }
});


if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("users", function () {
        return Meteor.users.find();  // This publishes everything - be careful!
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 1
The return here are good if you want to stop the execution of your function here.

Case 2
`Meteor.call` is asynchronous, so `if (error)` is not the next element on stack. You have to return `false` inside your event function, not inside the Meteor.call's callback.

```
Template.registration.events({
        "submit #register_form": function (event) {
            // This function is called when the registration form is submitted.

            event.preventDefault(); // Correct usage!

            var form_data = {
                username: event.target.username.value,
            };

            if (!Match.test(form_data.username, String)) {
                Session.set("message", "username must be a string");
                return false;  // 1 : Correct if you want to interrupt
            } 

            if (form_data.username.length < 6) {
                Session.set("message", "username must be at least 6 characters");
                return false;  // 1 : Correct if you want to interrupt
            }

            Meteor.call("check_username",form_data.username,function(error, result){
                if (error) {
                    Session.set("message", error);
                }
                if (result) {
                    Session.set("message", result);
                }
                //2: Was incorrect
            });
            //2
            return false;
        }
    });
```

PS: You have to understand that if the submit method doesn't return false, it will send the form to the `action` URL. So you have to return false before the execution reaches the end of the function.